# QT Maximizing widget in window

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to start my app maximized with the midget also maximized inside the MainWindow. I also need the widget to respond to the resizing of the main window, tried a few things but not quite got it working correctly. Any idea?

Thanks

[image]

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //this->setGeometry(50,50, 1280, 768);
    setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized);
    //MainWindow::showMaximized();
    m_pWebView = new QWebView(this);
    //set position and size
    m_pWebView->setGeometry(0,0,this->width(), this->height());
    m_pWebView->load(QUrl("http://csm.nathan"));
    //m_pWebView->show();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually when you create a new project in QtCreator, you should have a "centralWidget" in your QMainWindow.

Just ensure to use a QGridLayout in it:

```
this->centralWidget()->setLayout(new QGridLayout);
```

And then add your QWebView to this widget's layout:

```
this->centralWidget()->layout()->addWidget(m_pWebView);
```

This should do the job as far as your WebView is the only one element in the grid.

An other solution is to use the QtDesigner:

- First, add your webview or any other Widget inside your window
- Then click on the window background
- Then click on the "Layout in a grid" button

This will do exactly the same but be stored in the .ui file instead of your .cpp file.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and implement the example you provided :)

Comment: The important part is: You need a layout.

Comment: The only thing is I am implementing the WebView widget by code, there is no WebView widget that appears in the Design widget box? @JohannesS.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. However, it seems that Charles's answers did the trick. I just wanted to emphasize that incorrect/missing resize behaviour is usually caused by not having a layout.